# Can black holes effect light or just what the light reflects off of

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter

Can light be shifted or stopped by anything other than a solid? I ask because when observing black holes you can see light funneling into the sphere. My thought was that if what’s being pulled into the black hole is light or just a reflection of light off matter such as cosmic dust, dark matter or any material a drift in space? Also I cannot confirm any components of dark matter.

Comment: _All_ light, no matter the color, has no mass. What do you mean by "elements of space"?

Comment: I’m referring to matter a drift in the universe like cosmic dust or any matter I don’t comprehend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original title:

> Do different types of light differ in photon movement or mass [on hold]

In our present day physics of the world there are two main frameworks, one, the classical, emerging from the underlying quantum mechanical.

The word "light" is modeled in classical electrodynamics, which has no definition for "mass", although it has a definition for energy transfer with electromagnetic radiation, called [Poynting vector.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector)

The classical emerges from innumerable quantum mechanical entities called ["photons",](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon) which have zero mass, velocity c invacuum , energy= $hν$ where $h$  is the planck constant  constant and $ν$ the frequency of [the classical wave built up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) by innumerable of the same frequency photons.

These photons, as well as the light they build up, obey [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) equations, i.e. they are described by four vectors, $(E,p_x,p_y,p_z)$ , whose "length" is the zero mass of the photon. If two photons have an angle between them, the addition of their four vectors has an invariant mass. Thus light, which is built up of photons, can have an effective invariant mass, whose effect can be seen in the [radiation pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure) of light.

Color is defined by different frequencies of light, and all of the above describes all colors and all the electromagnetic [radiation spectrum.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum)

What can happen going through a prism, the velocity c, for light,( not for photons, ) is modified for different frequencies as the beam interacts with the medium, and part of the energy is lost due to the radiation pressure of the beam hitting the medium

> light doesn’t exist until it is generated so could what generates light

light/photons  are  generated at the quantum level by electromagnetic interactions of atoms and molecules.

> interact with elements of space to create the components of what we acknowledge and perceive on earth?

so this does not really make any sense.

**Edit** after drastic editing of question:

Present title:

> Can black holes effect light or just what the light reflects off of

and in the content:

> if what’s being pulled into the black hole is light

Photons are attracted to the gravitational sink which is the black hole, and "fall in" therefore we cannot see them, as they are single neutral  particles and do not radiate as they accelerate into the black hole.

> or just a reflection of light off of materials such as cosmic dust, dark matter or any material a drift in space?

This drifting material while falling in may reflect some of the photons, but this is a very small part of the light seen around a black hole. [The light comes from the accelerated charged particles](http://www.fisica.uniud.it/~deangeli/fismod/Radiation.pdf), molecules  that shed their electrons and become charged, so in-falling electrons and ions as they are being accelerated radiate photons, a lot of them in directions that can escape the black hole attractive gravitational sink, and thus be detected by our instruments.

> Also I cannot confirm any components of dark matter.

Dark matter is called dark because it does not interact with the electromagnetic force, so it cannot radiate any photons to a visible extent, as it would not be "dark".

Comment: Thank you, when I said elements of space I mean material like space dust, dark matter and other unknown materials. The main reason I mention the subject in reference to light is to determine if the light we see being sucked into a black whole is light itself or a reflection off “elements of space”.

Comment: The light coming from a black hole location is from the accelerated ions, charged particles, falling in the sink of the black hole.  We know what matter is made of so "elements" together with "space" is an undefined statement in physics.

Comment: Note taken, thank you for your knowledge. Ions are components that make up electrons and protons?

Comment: ions are what atoms and molecules become when shed of one or more electron. I have edited